# S3 access to only specific folder | client builder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, directory

I have access only to the specific folder in S3 bucket.
For S3 client builder I was using the following code for uploading to S3 bucket to the specified folder.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
                .build();
```

(I am running the code from server which has access to S3 so credentials not required,I was able to view the buckets and folders from cli)

```
putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(awsBucketName, fileName, multipartfile.getInputStream(), null)
```

I even tried giving bucketname along with prefix because I have access only for the specific folder.I was getting `access denied status 403`.
So for S3 client builder, I am trying to use endpoint configuration rather than just specifying the region. I got the following error.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTP))
                .build();

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: null
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
```

What should I do or how should I verify if it correctly maps to the bucket and folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it when I used Presigned URL(refer aws presigned url documentation which has the example code as well for java) to upload to a folder only for which you have access (that is you dont have access for the bucket)